# Samba authentication and LDAP

Tags: authentication, openldap, kerberos, samba4, authorization

I have an OpenLDAP server that I use for authentication and authorization for various services.
All users are of object type `inetOrgPerson` and my groups are `groupOfNames`.

Now I want to configure Samba to authenticate against LDAP as well (with group based authorization). I can't/don't want to use samba as domain controller, but solely as file server. I also don't want to manage user accounts separetely in samba, because I have all information I need in LDAP (user name, password, group memberships). I also want to avoid changing my DIT. As far as I can tell from my current research I cannot do this directly because

a) Samba uses its own credential store for authentication, meaning I'd have to `smbpasswd` for every existing LDAP user
b) My LDAP users would have to have samba attributes

After looking around some more I suspect that a solution to my problem could be to use Kerberos in between samba and LDAP.
I have no experience in administrating Kerberos, so before putting effort into that, I want to clarify following topics:

- Are my assumptions correct?
- Can I run Kerberos' Authentication Server and Key Distribution Center on one machine and configure it to only serve granting tickets on localhost? (OpenLDAP and samba run on the same machine)
- Will the usage of Kerberos allow me to keep my DIT unchanged and perform authentication/authorization exclusively with the information that is in LDAP?
- Are there better/easier solutions?

I'm on Ubuntu Server 14.04.

Thanks a lot for any hints in advance

Comment: Any news? (yes i know, some hours passed...)